# Python fails to find module when invoked as script ; finds it interactively

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to run a python script containing submodules from [Github](https://github.com/xinntao/Real-ESRGAN) to finetune its model.

The final step of the process is to invoke 
`python realesrgan/train.py -opt options/finetune_realesrgan_x4plus_pairdata.yml --auto_resume`

However, doing from root of repo (and from realesrgan folder for that matter) so results in:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Real-ESRGAN\realesrgan\train.py", line 5, in 
import realesrgan.archs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'realesrgan'

Yet, by launching python interactively from repo root (just "python") and then invoking
`import realesrgan.archs`

results in me being able to import it without any problem. All mentioned folders have required **init**.py in them.

This is my first time seeing discrepancy between calling a script and interactive python and I'm wondering, what can cause this.

System specifics just in case:
Windows 11

Python 3.9.9

python script execution fails from either powershell/cmd/file explorer

Comment: I assume you are not installing the package. `realesrgan` needs to be somewhere in the python path for the importer to find it. The path list is in `sys.path`. When you run the python interpreter, it includes `""` in the path... that is, the current working directory at the time of import. So, if you are in `D:\Real-ESRGAN`, you can import the package. But if you run the script, python puts *its* directory in `sys.path` and that's already `D:\Real-ESRGAN\realesrgan\`, and its not a subdirectory of itself.

Comment: If this package is installable, that would solve the problem. Otherwise, you could set `PYTHONPATH=D:\Real-ESRGAN` before running the script.